# How do I read in a text file as a string and extract just a single character? "0"

Tags: java, string, exception, character, java.util.scanner

How do I go about asking for a string input, then extracting the 0 character?
I was using "fstream.next()" and it would input whatever, not just a string.
I just need a character, which I can later use in a loop where the program only accepts char inputs of T, D, and E.

Then the program reads the double. Then the program calls the instance method with the parameters (char, double). The instance method later does it's thing and saves the inputs. The program later loops back and does it all over again.

Currently I am receiving an error "java.util.InputMismatchException". If you could offer suggestions, I'd greatly appreciate it! If clarification is needed, please let me know. Thank you in advance! :)

Here is my code:

```
    /** holds answer of whether user has more inputs or not */
    String answer;
    /** holds the results when calling inLetter() */
    char letter;
    /** holds the results when checking for types/strings in txt file */
    String inType = "";
    /** holds double results when searching line by line the text file */
    double inAmount = 0;
    /** holds the results when calling inAmount() */
    double amount;
    /** initiates infile to null */
    File infile = null;
    /** count system for how many valid lines were read and used */
    int count = 0; 

    /** calls description method */
    description();
    /** initiates new Object */
    GironEventClass newInput = new GironEventClass();
    try{
        /** defines new variable linked to .dat file */
        infile = new File("GironEvent.dat");
        /** calls fstream scanner - for use on file */
        Scanner fstream = new Scanner(infile);

        /** calls while loop. As long as there is a line, the loop continues */
        while(fstream.hasNext())
        {
            /** inputs first string in line of file to variable inType */
            inType = fstream.nextLine();
            char a_char = inType.charAt(0);

            /** inputs first int in line of file to variable inAmount */
            inAmount = fstream.nextDouble();

            try{
                /** calls instance method with two parameters */
                newInput.donations(a_char, inAmount);
                /** count ticket increases */
                count+=1;

            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException a){
                /** prints out error if exception is caught*/
                System.out.println("Just caught an illegal argument exception. ");
            }  

            }
        /** closes stream between program and fiel */
        fstream.close();

        /** outputs line count, and totals per type */
        System.out.println("\n" + count + " number of valid lines were read!\n");
        System.out.println("Total Sales: " + newInput.getSale());
        System.out.println("Donations: " + newInput.getDonated());
        System.out.println("Expenses: " + newInput.getExpenses());   
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        /** Outputs error if file cannot be opened. */
        System.out.println("\nGironEvent.dat could not be opened. ");
    }

    do{
        /** loop asks user if there is more that needs to be added to the totals. N exits loop. */
        System.out.print("\nAre there any more items to add that were not in the text file? (Type 'Y' or 'N'): ");
        answer = keyboard.next();
        if (("Y".equals(answer)) || ("y".equals(answer)))
        {
            letter = inLetter();
            amount = inAmount();

            newInput.donations(letter, amount);
        }

    }while (("Y".equals(answer)) || ("y".equals(answer)));
    /** calls instance method to display totals in a fancy manner */
    newInput.display();
}

/** inLetter - displays types to user. Asks user to input type. Converts input into uppercase letter.
 * 
 * @return resultTwo - Uppercase form of result. Result is the type the user inputted.
 */
public static char inLetter(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String result;
    String resultTwo;

    System.out.println("T = Tiket Sales");
    System.out.println("D = Donations");
    System.out.println("E = Expenses");
    System.out.print("Please input an identifier ");
    result = keyboard.nextLine();
    resultTwo = result.toUpperCase();

    return resultTwo;    
}

/** inAmount - asks user for amount. Tests that amount isn't a negative number or a zero.
 * 
 * @return result - the amount the user inputed. regardless if it was the first or tenth time. 
 */
public static double inAmount(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double result;

    System.out.println("Please input an amount ");
    result = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if(result <= 0){
        System.out.print("Please input a positive and non-zero amount ");
        result = keyboard.nextDouble();
    }

    return result;
}
/** description - displays a description of what the program does
 * void.
 */
public static void description(){
    System.out.println("The program will ask you what amount is being spent on what.");
    System.out.println("    ex: expenses, ticket sales, and profts.");
    System.out.println("This program will help determine whether the event generated or lost money.");      
}
```

I need assistance with the following block:

```
 /** inputs first string in line of file to variable inType */
            inType = fstream.nextLine();
            char a_char = inType.charAt(0);

            /** inputs first int in line of file to variable inAmount */
            inAmount = fstream.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fstream is having a combination of String and Double.

So when you use fstream.nextDouble() it throws java.util.InputMismatchException

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()

You can first check whether the next character is double or not with the method hasNextDouble()

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble()

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Clement. I will try this as soon as I get home. Just for clarification, when using fstream, can you only have one kind of input? Example, just doubles, or just ints, or just strings? You can't have a combination of both? Thank you!

Comment: You can have a combination of Double, Int and String, but you need to take care while parsing it. If you are sure your data only has Double, then we can use nextDouble().

Comment: I get it now! Request fstream string then parse into char and/or double, and record it into a variable. I get it now! Thank you Clement. Let me test it out and I'll give you the check mark. :)